# What is the proper way to use `.setTimeout()` in a Promise chain?

Tags: angular, typescript

In the application that I am building, there is a use case where I need to raise a first API call, wait for the response, then use the information in the response to raise a second API call. Something like this:

```
firstAPI.call(some input)
            .then(firstResponse => {
                return secondAPI.call(firstResponse);
            })
            .then((secondResponse) => {
                //do something
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
```

These all worked fine. However, currently for some reason, the second API call cannot be raised immediately after the first one, and there has to be some interval before it can work. I then tried to use `.setTimeout()` like this:

```
firstAPI.call(some input)
            .then(firstResponse => {
                //save the response somewhere
            })
            .then(() => {
                // Wait 1.5s before calling the second API
                return this.sleep(1500);
            })
            .then(() => {
                return secondAPI.call(saved first response);
            })
            .then((secondResponse) => {
                //do something
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });

private sleep(milliseconds: number): Promise<Object> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds)
        });
    }
```

And I tested this code piece for below scenarios:

1) Both first and second call succeed - worked fine and did sleep for 1.5s;

2) First call fails - worked fine with error being caught;

3) First call succeed but second call fails - **didn't work; the error was not caught!** Unit test code piece as follows:

```
 describe('when first call succeeds but second call fails', () => {
        it('should log errorMsg', fakeAsync(() => {
            let mockFirstResponse: Promise<Object> = Promise.resolve(some mock response);            
            spyOn(firstAPI, 'call').and.returnValue(mockFirstResponse);
            spyOn(secondAPI, 'call').and.returnValue(Promise.reject(new Error('Oops!')));
            spyOn(console, 'error').and.callThrough();

            underTest.submit(); // Call my function
            tick(1500);

            expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }));
    });
```

Unit test failed with error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Oops!
>           at resolvePromise (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:469:0 <- configuration/karma/karma-entry.js:128867)
>           at webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:528:0 <- configuration/karma/karma-entry.js:128926

The `.catch` block wasn't executed at all.

My hypothesis is that `.setTimeout()` breaks the chain somehow. What is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: Do you have to follow a chaining .then approach or can you try to do something like `setTimeout( () => { /* second api call */ }, milliseconds)` or `return this.sleep(1500, () => { /* second api call */  })`

Comment: So what happens when the second call fails then? Is the next `then` block executed? Can you show us the code from ` secondAPI.call` please?

Comment: I have to use chain because the response from first call is needed for raising second call. When the second call fails, the following `then` is expected not to be executed (since the call failed); however what surprised me is that the `catch` block was not executed :|

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your code is doing something very similar but give this a whirl.

Introduce a new promise to the chain which does nothing but delay execution of the next block in the chain like so:

```
firstAPI.call(someinput)
  .then(firstResponse => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(firstResponse);
      }, 1500)
    })
  })
  .then(firstResponse => {
    return secondAPI.call(firstResponse);
  })
  .then((secondResponse) => {
    // do something
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

At a total guess, the reason for the need for the delay may be due to the server, after responding, carrying out some processing which takes a sec or two to complete or it maybe re-indexing or some jiggery-pokery.

Comment: Thanks, while still unit test fails with same error "Uncaught (in promise)" on this line: `spyOn(secondAPI, 'call').and.returnValue(Promise.reject(new Error('Oops!')));`

Is there anything wrong with the unit test code or production code?

Comment: is this code in a method that returns a promise? If so then the calling code prob needs a catch block

Comment: no, this is a void method, and 'secondResponse' is used to set up values to be displayed on corresponding component.html

Comment: Where it says ... //do something ... secondResponse is a rejected promise that has not been caught I believe ... instead you prob want to mock the HTTP response - in mocha you do this with "nock" but Ive never done it with Jasmine - look around for libs, this might be good ... https://lazamar.github.io/testing-http-requests-with-jasmine/ ... a non-2xx mocked reponse should hit your catch block